# AJAX return empty page when i use .print() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I wrote script to printing page with used AJAX. I fighting with this shit three days, but i don't know whats problem with this is it.

If i generate blank page and print it manually - its okay.

If i generate blank page and print it with .print() function in my script it returns empty white page.

What's wrong?

```
$.post({
    type: "POST",
    url: "create.php",
    data: {pid: pid, price: price, contractor: contractor, netto: netto, brutto: brutto, delivery: delivery, amount: amount},
}).done(function() {
    $.post({
        type: "POST",
        url: "generate.php",
        data: {pid: pid},
    }).done(function(data) {
        printPage = window.open('');
        printPage.document.writeln('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="offer.css" /></head><body>' +data+ '</body></html>');
        printPage.document.close();
        printPage.focus();
        printPage.print();
        printPage.close();  
    });
});
```

Comment: If you console.log(data) does it display anything?

Comment: If i delete print() function and open data in new blank window i se normal content. Problem is with printing. I see empty page all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried to simulate behavior, and you are right. It prints empty page. Reason for this is that you are executing print() before page is rendered.

If you replace

```
printPage.print();
printPage.close();
```

with

```
setTimeout(function(){
     printPage.print();
     printPage.close();
}, 2000);
```

it would print content. I personally don't like setTimeout kind of solutions, but this is just to illustrate what is wrong with code.

Comment: How can i try to print page after load with better way?

Comment: Well, you could replace whole post to generate.php with window.open('generate.php?pid='+pid, '_blank'), and in php you could render page and add print statement inside document ready event.